# How to use the keyword 'with' on an interface without knowing the underlying record type?

Tags: c#, interface, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

In C#, is there a way of using the `with` keyword on an interface, without knowing the type (or base type) of the object?

I'm imagining something like the `DoSomething` method in the following pseudo-code (which is not valid c#). The code `DoSomething` would be expected to act on all records that implement `ISomeRecord`.

The `DoSomething2` method would compile, but work only in records of type `SomeRecord` and not of records of types other than `SomeRecord`.

```
public interface ISomeRecord
{
  bool SomeProp { get; }
}

public record SomeRecord : ISomeRecord 
{ 
  public bool SomeProp { get; init; } 
}

public class SomeUtil
{
  public ISomeRecord DoSomething(ISomeRecord rec)
  {
    return ( rec as record ) with { SomeProp = false };
  }
  public ISomeRecord DoSomething2(ISomeRecord rec)
  {
    return ( rec as SomeRecord ) with { SomeProp = false };
  }
  public ISomeRecord DoSomething3<T>(T rec) where T : struct, ISomeRecord
  {
    return rec with { SomeProp = false };
  }
}
```

As an aside, in C# 10 (in preview at moment of writing) I notice that `DoSomething3` compiles. C# 10 introduces `record structs` and `record classes`. The latter is the default. It appears what I'm after is possible for `record struct` objects, but not for `record class` objects. In other words, in the example,`DoSomething3` can't be called with a `SomeRecord` as an argument unless `SomeRecord` is changed to a `record struct`.

I don't see a way to do the same with a `record class` which is what I need in my use case.

Comment: I wouldn't expect DoSomething to compile, as an interface isn't a record.  You could add an abstract record you inherit from that implements the interface, but I don't think that's what you're looking for as you'll still have to use the abstract record type and not the interface for your SomeUtil methods.

Comment: Hi @Zer0, Yes. It's the general case that I'm after. That is the case where we want to apply the DoSomething logic to *any record that implements* `ISomeRecord`. IE not restiricted to those inheriting from the SomeRecord base class.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that's possible.  But maybe someone smarter than me has an answer.  You also can't where with as a generic constraint AFAIK, so not a lot of options if you want this to be at interface level.